# can I use service link instead of load balancer?

Tags: rancher

Both load balancer and service link can achieve high avaliability of service.
Load balancer make it by a proxy, while service link by DNS.

Because this DNS is only belong to Rancher itself, public service can only use load balancer to distribute requests.

But to internal service, if service link is the same with load balancer ?
Can service link be used for high avaliability ?

Whether the request may not be distributed balancedly because of DNS cache ?

For example:

Service `backend`, with 3 containers, `backend_1`, `backend_2`, `backend_3`

Service nginx, make a `proxy_pass` to `backend`.

**Would it always pass to `backend_1`, because once it DNS to `backend_1` and it will always use `backend_1` ?**

In other word, **can I use service link instead of load balancer for internal service ?**

Answer (score 0):

This was asked and answered on the Rancher forum: https://forums.rancher.com/t/load-balancer-or-service-link/4719/2

Depending on the client behavior, the answer is somewhere between "does not balance properly at all" and "works ok as a simple way to coarsely balance requests".

The DNS server will return an answer with *all* of the IPs of the (healthy) `backend` containers in random order each time it asked, with a TTL of 1 second.

But the client is free to do whatever it likes with this information.  Some will take just the first answer, others pick randomly from the list, or [not so randomly](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/3495).  Some will respect the TTL, others will cache the value for some amount of time they decide, or forever, or until a request fails, etc.

Nginx specifically will resolve names exactly once on startup by default.  To make it do anything else you have to give it a [resolver](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver).  The Rancher DNS service is always `169.254.169.250` on any host.

Comment: Could you please try to include the relevant parts of the link in your answer? Links tend to break, which would leave this question unanswered. See [How-To-Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for additional information.